# SharePoint 2016 Backup

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, backup

We have SP2016 Topology 2 servers for each
2 APP Servers
2 DC  Servers
2 FE  Servers
2 SC  Servers
1 SQL Server

This Farm never have Back UP before and I would like to perform backup for the first time, My question is Can I perform Backup from CA and does it make any difference from which server or servers I need
to perform the Backup and if I need to restore do I need to restore from the same server.
or is it better to use PowerShell.
Also do I need to backup IIS setting?
what is the best practice?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you read over the section [Overview of backup and recovery in SharePoint Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/sharepoint/administration/backup-and-recovery-overview). This will provide you with the best guidance for out of the box backup and recovery solutions for Sharepoint.

It does not make a difference which server you perform the backup from, but you need to back up to a UNC share. Creating that UNC share on a separate disk on the SQL server will be the fastest possible backup you can perform (as `Backup-SPFarm` or backing up from Central Admin will also perform a SQL database backup).

In general, for larger farms, the best bet is to use a SQL backup tool, either the native SQL backup capabilities or a 3rd party tool. You can then script the farm creation which will provide you with a consistent rebuild mechanism. Alternatively, you can create a configuration only backup via `Backup-SPFarm -ConfigurationOnly` which will export the configuration of the Config database to the file system, which you can then restore to a *new* farm.

You do not need to backup IIS as that is taken care of by the SharePoint backup (full farm or configuration only).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read the [Plan for backup and recovery in SharePoint Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/backup-and-recovery-planning).

You can perform backup in the CA and can not perform restore on the same server. You can refer to [the article](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/sharepoint-2016-central-admin-backup-and-restore-perform-a-site-collection-b/).

If you have a large server farm or store too much data, it is recommended that you use SQL backup tools. More information, please read [this article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/back-up-a-farm).

Answer (score 0):

Backups levels:

1. DB
2. Farm By CA
3. Webapp  By CA
4. Site collection By PowerShell
5. VM By Hyper-V Manager

Comment: Online VM backups are not supported for SharePoint server farms.